# How can I write my CPU temperature to a file on an Intel Mac?

Tags: macos, cpu, terminal, zsh

I'd like to log my Mac CPU temperature to a disk file in the Mac terminal. I've tried:

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers smc | grep -i "CPU die temperature" >> cpu_temps.txt
```

...and:

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers smc | grep -i "CPU die temperature" | sudo tee -a /Users/my_mac/temp_log.txt >/dev/null
```

...and:

```
while true
   do
   sudo powermetrics --samplers smc | grep -i "CPU die temperature" >> cpu_temps.txt
   sleep 1
done
```

...but nothing is logged to the output file.

What is the correct way to do this?

FWIW, here is the output of the command:

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers smc | grep -i "CPU die temperature"
CPU die temperature: 78.89 C
CPU die temperature: 77.38 C
CPU die temperature: 75.99 C
CPU die temperature: 74.62 C
CPU die temperature: 73.45 C
```

Comment: Do you have an output with your command : `sudo powermetrics --samplers smc | grep -i "CPU die temperature"` ?

Comment: `sudo powermetrics --samplers smc 2>&1` ? See `man bash`, hit `/` and type a single space followed by `+Redirecting Output` and hit enter.

Comment: @hidigoudi, I have updated the original post to show output.

Comment: @Hannu, I tried `sudo powermetrics samplers smc 2>/Users/my_mac_user/Downloads/temperature.txt +Redirecting Output`, but it is sending output to the console and not to the file. Does it have to fill a buffer with 32k or so of text before the buffer is flushed to disk?

Comment: It doesn’t matter that you Mac is Intel. What does matter is your macOS version.

Comment: @VikR `2>` redirects only errors (STDERR), it's for that you still have output to the console.

Comment: @hidigoudi, I'm not as expert in this as you are. Could you please provide the complete command?

Comment: `sudo powermetrics --samplers smc -n 1 >> /Users/my_mac_user/Downloads/temperature.txt 2>&1` - But you can follow the @Giacomo1968's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the sample rate (`-i`) to `1ms` and setting the sample count (`-n`) to `1` like this:

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers smc -n 1 -i 1ms | grep -i "CPU die temperature" >> cpu_temps.txt
```

And then set it in your Bash script like this:

```
while true
   do
   sudo powermetrics --samplers smc -n 1 -i 1ms | grep -i "CPU die temperature" >> cpu_temps.txt
   sleep 1;
done
```

The issue is that `powermetrics` is constantly polling stats. Essentially forever until you manual stop it the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. So you need to alter the sample rate (`-i`) and sample count (`-n`), as explained in the man page, to get it to behave as you would like it to:

```
-i N, --sample-rate N
        sample every N ms (0=disabled) [default: 5000ms]

-n N, --sample-count N
        Obtain N periodic samples (0=infinite) [default: 0]
```

So setting `-i 1ms` effectively disables the `powermetrics` sample rate which defaults to 5 seconds (aka: 5000ms) and `-n 1` assures that `powermetrics` gets exactly one sample, then stops and writes it to `cpu_temps.txt`.

Comment: I ran:

`sudo powermetrics --samplers smc -n 1 | grep -i "CPU die temperature" >> cpu_temps.txt`

As you noted, it outputs the temperature to the file, but only once. I'd like it to log to the file once per second. I tried:

`sudo powermetrics --samplers smc -n 10 | grep -i "CPU die temperature" >> cpu_temps.txt`

It waited 10 seconds or so, then output 10 log lines and exited. I'd like it to output the log line once per second. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @VikR I just added a variant that uses your Bash script example with the new command line that used `-n 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I've built https://github.com/lavoiesl/osx-cpu-temp

```
$ ./osx-cpu-temp 
57.4 °C
```